# Conditional types for callback parameters

Tags: typescript, types

These are my types:

```js
export type Mapping =
    | {
          type: 'ok';
          data: Record<string, string>;
      }
    | {
          type: 'error';
          data: Error;
      };

export type Payload<T> = Extract<Mapping, { type: T }>['data'];

export interface Callback<T> {
    (data: Payload<T>): void;
}

export type Store = {
    [K in Mapping['type']]: Set<Callback<K>>;
};
```

This is my code:

```js
const storage: Store = {
    ok: new Set(),
    error: new Set(),
};

function store<T extends Mapping['type']>(
    type: T,
    callback: Callback<T>
): void {
    storage[type].add(callback);
}
```

The error I get:

```
Argument of type 'Callback<T>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Callback<"ok"> & Callback<"error">'.
  Type 'Callback<T>' is not assignable to type 'Callback<"ok">'.
    Types of parameters 'data' and 'data' are incompatible.
      Type 'Record<string, string>' is not assignable to type 'Payload<T>'.
        Type 'Record<string, string>' is not assignable to type 'Extract<{ type: "error"; data: Error; }, { type: T; }>["data"]'.
          Type 'Record<string, string>' is missing the following properties from type 'Error': name, messagets(2345)
```

I want to achieve, that if some callback is stored in either `storage.ok` or `storage.error` can deal the correct parameter type. So I tried to use conditional types, to add more options for the callback parameter types easily. I think the error is in `'Callback<"ok"> & Callback<"error">'` because it shouldn't be `&`. But where is the error? The `storage` has the correct type:

```js
type Store = {
    error: Set<Callback<"error">>;
    ok: Set<Callback<"ok">>;
}
```

*Edit*: The problem comes from the `.add` function:

```
(method) Set<T>.add(value: Callback<"ok"> & Callback<"error">): Set<Callback<"ok">> | Set<Callback<"error">>
```

Where comes the `&` from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a failure of the compiler to perform the higher-order type analysis necessary to verify that what you are doing inside the implementation of `store()` is safe.

---

Let's define `PickStore<T>`, like this:

```
type PickStore<T extends Mapping['type']> = { [K in T]: Set<Callback<K>> };
```

This is essentially the same as `Pick<Store, T>` and therefore a supertype of `Store`, *but the compiler cannot do the higher-order type analysis to verify that*.  For any *specific* value of `T`, the compiler can see that `PickStore<T>` is a supertype of `Store`:

```
const sOk: PickStore<"ok"> = storage; // okay
const sError: PickStore<"error"> = storage; // okay
const sBoth: PickStore<"ok" | "error"> = storage; // okay
const sNeither: PickStore<never> = storage; // okay
```

But when you try to do the same for a *generic* `T`, the compiler balks:

```
function test<T extends Mapping['type']>() {
  const sT: PickStore<T> = storage; // error!
  // Type 'Store' is not assignable to type 'PickStore<T>'
}
```

And this is your problem.  If you could widen `storage` to `PickStore<T>` inside of the `store` function, the compiler would be able to see that `storage[type]` is of type `Set<Callback<T>>`, and therefore you'd be able to `add()` the `callback` parameter with no issue.

Instead, the compiler only understands that `storage[type]` is assignable to the *union* `Set<Callback<"ok">> | Set<Callback<"error">`.  This is true, but not specific enough for your purposes.  The *correlation* between `storage[type]` and `callback` is lost.  (See [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) for issues surrounding the compiler's inability to keep track of the correlation in type between several values.)  So the `add()` method is seen as the *union* of two function types.  And, when you [call a union of function types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-3.html#improved-behavior-for-calling-union-types), the compiler requires the *intersection* of its parameters, to guarantee type safety.  (If you know that you have a function that's either an `X`-taker or a `Y`-taker but you're not sure which, you'd better give it an `X & Y` to be safe.)

---

I'd recommend that, in cases like this where the compiler is unable to verify some higher-order type analysis, you use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to just tell the compiler that what you're doing is safe.  This shifts the burden of guaranteeing safety from the compiler to you, so you should be careful.  Anyway it could look like this:

```
function store<T extends Mapping['type']>(
  type: T,
  callback: Callback<T>
): void {
  (storage as any as PickStore<T>)[type].add(callback);
}
```

Here we've just asserted to the compiler that `storage` can be treated like a `PickStore<T>` (and we need the intermediate assertion through `unknown` or `any` because the compiler really has trouble with the relationship).  After that hurdle, the rest of the line goes through without a problem.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCyBDMYCWA7AczgF4AoOOAHzgG9yKFlgAuOAcggGs2BueigCYYYGVgCVgAY2gCAPAGcYUfAQA0cRcsIA+PhQC+9anQaMUrNsChRovfnCEjWAUWvQ9cfX1KhIsM6gAChiIADYQGHIAKtokcM4gShiSMLKY2CrqNAGsUZ7aANpsjhhsALrevtDw+DBWAGbJqADCGKGhAEbJnLIxtPQAFCWswWER0doAlKwAbhA4AnyGPuDVAXAAyjDQqMT9FAUA0nD46Fi4hEVIKOVlrBvAqa3tXZI9h9q6pF6kpNJ4ig02ygGAILE2wN2+zgXFYeGAAHdNo8BpNVPQrDYoHDEciYKj0T9SPUAK54FI4CB4OAYeRRJi9bQDECsDB4RDTGnyeRWGDyOAgE78vLZZbXII4N5bHa9OCgOp4AT89IXAhXJjlWJ7bJHE7UqJ3PGyZ6dbqyD6xH7-QHyADynBGks40qgwFkACIuO6tUDoKDgDw4AB6IMwzghP5Um2uLGOqWQj2Y6DeuKKP1gwMhsMR63weQAIQgMAAFnHnQnPZx3VQ4O6k1AU3s0yCM8HQ1wc1G8wA5YA4EtWMsut3wmZWH3N-2Z9vhxC-UnkmCU6l1RSy+XARXK84qdU3MpMybQ3MaKJDhN9JvAqdtuVuKAAQnoWfpKHYw7YQrgeCLXPkOAIPAMA6UJUG2dY2ECJ1h0ZNhvnnMkKSpX1XXXRJNyVM4MkuNhxU1AZ6HFXJ0QoSQ2lNN5WBNV4ehiUhOTmBZoQGScwS5Gl2XYqD4xlGJJgKcUygAOkiAQBjIl5ukmJZflkoA)

Comment: Great answer, this should be accepted over mine.

One tiny correction: in the first paragraph you wrote "the implementation of `test()`" but I think you meant "the implementation of `store()`".

Comment: So its indeed a typescript error. Thank you for your time, I accept this answer although I hope there will be a better solution in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The problem has to do with how `Payload` is defined. [Changing it to an intersection works](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCyBDMYCWA7AczgF4AoOCuAHzgG9zLGKkUAuOAcggGsOBuBk0oATDDAzsASsADG0YQB4AzjCj4CAGjgq1hAHwChAX0HU6poS2DsOwKFGj8LTUePYBRe9ENMjA0qCQsAjIqAAKGIgANhAYigAqeiRwABSY2OpwAGR0IWxw8XBGAJQA2hyuGBwAuv6B0PD4MHYAZhgyqADCGFFRAEbt3AqJ5owplewR0bEJesXsAG4QOMICJgHgDXmoAMow0KjEo5SlANJw+OhYuITlVjXV7DvAMArdvQMyQ6d6BqR+pFIcjwKm0+ygGAI1jgewOyXojB47DwwAA7jCXilihpTHYHFBkWiMTAsTiAaQWgBXPAyGA4CB4MEHYZwUDNPDCJRXDK3Dj3ap6FKmKzseI4xgyHr9Qbsd7Sr7DPSkeZwJYrY4UFTQSHAUpWaoAOjiwhSko+g2KayAA):

```js
type Payload<T> = (Mapping & { type: T })['data']
```

---

**EDIT:** As pointed out in the comments, this is probably not what you want. It's no different from `type Payload = Mapping['data']`. Apologies for not looking more closely before answering.

Comment: Discriminating a union by generic intersection doesn't work the way you want here, I fear.  It makes `Callback<"ok">` and `Callback<"error">` indistinguishable types.  The error goes away in the example code, but now a `Callback<"ok">` must take an argument of type `Record<string, string> | Error` which is not the intent.  I expect the OP will quickly run into problems trying to actually use these `Callback` types.

Comment: @jcalz good point. Somehow I thought that's what was desired but now that I'm looking at the type signature for `store` again it's probably not.

Comment: And if it was desired then `Payload` could just be `type Payload = Mapping['data']` anyhow. That's what I get for playing with types before having coffee.

Comment: I could have used function overloading but I wanted a more dynamic solution to always have the correct parameter type in my callback functions. But yea... now my brain hurts :D